# ViewGroup in event listener

Tags: android, android-layout, android-inflate, android-event

I am trying to include a new layout on an event. For that I am using LayoutInflater in That event listener. But the problem is, `LayoutInflater.inflate()` function expect its parameters to be `(Int) ResourceId, ViewGroup`. I am unable to figure out what to use as ViewGroup in the event listener. `this` refers to that event listener. `parent` and `item` are both views, not ViewGroups. Please help.

Comment: Usually you send the view, that the view you are inflating is gonna be in (it's parent). A view can also be a ViewGroup, by inheriting the class. So if your view is for example, A linear-, relative- or framelayout, they are also a ViewGroup, and you should just cast them like this (ViewGroup)view. See here for more info: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html (click on 'Known Direct Subclasses', to view which other views are also ViewGroups).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're attaching it to your activity, use that.  If, however, you want a floating view, make your call as follows:

```
View view = inflater.inflate(resourceId, null, false);
```

This will create it and allow you to add it as a view to whatever you please.